# Invalid choice: 'batch-get-secret-value' AWS BatchGetSecretValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

Batch secrets retrieval was recently added to the AWS Secret Manager to allow getting multiple secrets. See the document https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/aws-secrets-manager-batch-retrieval-secrets/

However, when I use the command specified in the documentation ( `BatchGetSecretValue`), I get an error as below:

```
aws secretsmanager batch-get-secret-value  --secret-id-list X_L1YX95, X_GIRNAK, X_M8CM8D
```

error :

```
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

Reference documentation for CLI commands - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/batch-get-secret-value.html

Comment: Update your awscli.

Comment: @jarmod to which version ? I currently have `aws-cli/2.13.14`

Answer (score 0):

Update your installation of awscli to the latest, or anything from 2.13.39 onwards, when support for BatchGetSecretValue was added, according to the releases [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst).

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.15.10 Python/3.11.6 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

And help for batch-get-secret-value:

```
# aws secretsmanager batch-get-secret-value help

batch-get-secret-value
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Description
***********

Retrieves the contents of the encrypted fields "SecretString" or
"SecretBinary" for up to 20 secrets. To retrieve a single secret, call
GetSecretValue .
```